# Can you have multiple clipping regions in an HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clipping

I have code that loads a bunch of images into hidden img elements and then a Javascript loop which places each image onto the canvas. However, I want to clip each image so that it is a circle when placed on the canvas.

My loop looks like this:

```
    $$('#avatars img').each(function(avatar) {
        var canvas = $('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x+24, y+24, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, 1);
        context.clip();

        context.strokeStyle = "black";

        context.drawImage(document.getElementById(avatar.id), x, y);

        context.stroke();
    });
```

Problem is, only the first image is drawn (or is visible).

If I remove the clipping logic:

```
    $$('#avatars img').each(function(avatar) {
        var canvas = $('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

        context.drawImage(document.getElementById(avatar.id), x, y);
    });
```

Then all my images are drawn.

Is there a way to get each image individually clipped?

I tried resetting the clipping area to be the entire canvas between images but that didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try to save current context state and then restore it:

```
        canvas = document.getElementById("area");
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        $("#avatars img").each(function(avatar) {

            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

            context.save();//push current state into canvas
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x + 24, y + 24, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, 1);
            context.clip();

            context.strokeStyle = "black";

            //draw image this way
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = avatar.src;
            img.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(img, x, y);
            };

            context.stroke();
            context.restore();//restore context to the state

        });
```

I think when you call drawImage method,you also need to set image parameter as an Image class by adding a source line which is already in your **avatar.src parameter**.

You should check the reference document for [Canvas State](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-state)

Comment: save/restore - that was it! thank you so much.

not sure though about your recommendation to draw the images differently. te drawimage code works fine the way i have it now, what would be the benefit of using the code you provided?

Comment: That's simple,you dont need to add all image files into the page.Showing source into Image() class will be enough.Benefit of removing those allows your page not load those images on page load.It's page load (performance issue) time we're talking about :)