# How to set a custom clipping zone for HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, clip

I need to draw on a rectangle minus a circle. If the circle clipping is not possible, a polygonal clipping zone could be enough for my need.

How do I set a custom clipping zone for HTML5 Canvas?

Comment: Hey have a look at this question on stack-overflow if it helps you <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551411/can-you-have-multiple-clipping-regions-in-an-html-canvas">Clipping circles on Canvas</a>

Comment: yeap. it's near what I'm looking for. except that I do not succed to not trace the border of the circle, and I'm looking for excluding the circle not keeping it !

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing) in the Canvas tutorial, it explains how you draw a rectangle minus a circle and similar figures.

I think you are looking for `destination-out`:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "#09f";
    ctx.fillRect(15,15,70,70);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

    ctx.fillStyle = "#f30";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(75,75,35,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.fill();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"/>
</body>
</html>
```

See it in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPX3w/).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use "clip" and than - "clear". Something like that:

```
drawRectangle(ctx);
walkCirclePath(ctx);
ctx.clip();
ctx.clear();
```

But antialiasing dont work in such way;

Comment: There is no clear() function for the [canvas context](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-measuretext). But a clip should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well.
It was hard.

The best solution I found to draw every where except in a circle is

```
c.save();
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, 0);
c.lineTo(x, 0);
c.arc(x, y, 75, - Math.PI / 2, Math.PI * 2 - Math.PI / 2, 1);
c.lineTo(x, 0);
c.lineTo(1000, 0);
c.lineTo(1000, 500);
c.lineTo(0, 500);
c.clip();
c.drawImage(window.tBitmap[0], x - 100, y - 100);
c.restore();
```

I can't believe taht there is not a better solution. But it's works for my need.

Comment: Yes, but I do not succeed to use it. I'll try again, but I was quite hurry so I used the first working solution ;)