# More than one clip call per context in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I cannot seem to get a second clip call working in canvas. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2hL17nu/ 
Notice how the first radial grad is clipped but the second isn't.

I have seen [Can you have multiple clipping regions in an HTML Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551411/can-you-have-multiple-clipping-regions-in-an-html-canvas) but save restore still doesn't seem to be letting the next clip() work.

Thanks in advance for your help. See code below:

```
var x1 = 300,
    y1 = 100,
    x2 = 50,
    y2 = 50,
    r = 20;

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
function createRadialGradient (xa, ya, xb, yb, r) {
    var grd = context.createRadialGradient(xa, ya, 0, xb, yb, r);
    grd.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
    grd.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    context.fillStyle = grd;
    context.fill();
}
context.save();
context.rect(x1-r,y1-r,r,r);
context.clip();
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
createRadialGradient(x1, y1, x1, y1, r);

context.restore();

context.save();
context.rect(x2-r,y2,r,r);
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.clip();
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
createRadialGradient(x2, y2, x2, y2, r);

context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use beginPath() and closePath() before drawing the clips and after the clip() methods respectively:

```js
var x1 = 300,
    y1 = 100,
    x2 = 50,
    y2 = 50,
    r = 20;

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
function createRadialGradient (xa, ya, xb, yb, r) {
    var grd = context.createRadialGradient(xa, ya, 0, xb, yb, r);
    grd.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
    grd.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    context.fillStyle = grd;
    context.fill();
}
context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.rect(x1-r,y1-r,r,r);
context.closePath();
context.clip();
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
createRadialGradient(x1, y1, x1, y1, r);

context.restore();

context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.rect(x2-r,y2,r,r);
context.closePath();
context.clip();
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
createRadialGradient(x2, y2, x2, y2, r);

context.stroke();
```

```html
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: You need a beginPath() for the new drawing shape after clipping or the clipping rect will be part of fill/stroke etc. (as closePath does not clear the path). closePath is really not necessary with clip(), but if you still want to use it make sure it's called *before* calling clip().

Answer (score 2):

The `save()` and `restore()` does not affect the content of the path object itself - only the state of the context (which includes clipping state).

`restore()` can remove the clip definition but if the path still contains data it will be activated next time you call clip regardless, together with new data added to the path.

To make it work you need to make sure you're working with a clean path. For that simply call `beginPath()` before defining the clip area with `rect()`. `closePath()` is really not necessary with `clip()` as `clip()` (and `fill()`) will close implicit due to it being impossible to clip with an open path.

Then before doing actual drawing call `beginPath()` again as clipping is now a part of the context state. Finally use `restore()` to remove the clipping definition (revert state to previous).

```
context.save();               // store current state to stack

context.beginPath();          // clean path
context.rect(x1-r,y1-r,r,r);
context.clip();               // path is closed; clip is now activated

context.beginPath();          // clean path for your new shape
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
createRadialGradient(x1, y1, x1, y1, r);
...

context.restore();            // removes the clip from state
```

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(50, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.clip();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = '#900';
ctx.fill();

ctx.restore();

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(150, 80, 80, 60);
ctx.clip();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = '#009';
ctx.fill();

ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=180></canvas>
```